# Where to find a download for X3D-Edit 3.3

Tags: x3d

I used to have X3D-Edit 3.3 downloaded and working on my Netbeans IDE but I updated my laptop to Windows 10 and some of my files got deleted such as X3D-Edit and when I go onto `https://savage.nps.edu/X3D-Edit/X3D-Edit.html`, I get

```
This web page is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Google Chrome could not load the web page because savage.nps.edu took too long to respond. The website may be down or you may be experiencing issues with your Internet connection.
Check your Internet connection
Check any cables and reboot any routers, modems or other network devices you may be using.
Allow Chrome to access the network in your firewall or antivirus settings.
If it is already listed as a programme that is allowed to access the network, try removing it from the list and adding it again. 
If you use a proxy server...
Check your proxy settings or contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy server is working. If you don't believe you should be using a proxy server: Go to the Chrome menu > Settings > + Show advanced settings > Change proxy settings... > LAN Settings and deselect "Use a proxy server for your LAN".
```

I've tried that same site on two separate networks and I've tried it with and without a firewall. And I'm still getting the same problem, so I was wondering where I'd get X3D-Edit from?

Comment: I can reach it from https://savage.nps.edu/X3D-Edit/X3D-Edit3.3.zip Did you try it again?

Answer (score 0):

Happy to announce that upgraded X3D-Edit 4.0 now available

- https://savage.nps.edu/X3D-Edit/X3D-Edit.html

Update: installers and help video now available on SourceForge

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/x3d/files

Downloadable zip includes runnable versions for Windows, Mac and Linux.  Build environment is Apache NetBeans 12.6 and openjdk 19.  Beta testing in progress, adding features and X3D4 nodes with special focus on validation, HTML5 integration and Web Audio API.

All test and usage reports welcome.  Have fun with X3D4!